# one-to-many append attribute error

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Bit of a noob with SQLAlchemy (and Python, though less so).

Can't seem to straighten out relationships between my Post and Picture models.
Post objects should have a list called 'gallery', a list of related Picture objects.  As well there is a Post 'cover', an individual Picture chosen as the gallery cover.  I'm also trying to use OrderingList to maintain picture order in the gallery.

When attempting to append pictures to the post.gallery in my view it throws the following:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Here are the models:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cover_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pictures.id',
            use_alter=True, name='fk_post_cover_id'))
    picture_ids = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pictures.id',
            use_alter=True, name='fk_post_picture_ids'))
    cover = db.relationship('Picture', foreign_keys=cover_id, post_update=True)
    gallery = db.relationship('Picture', foreign_keys=picture_ids,
            order_by='Picture.position',
            collection_class=ordering_list('position'))

class Picture(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pictures'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    position = db.Column(db.Integer)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
```

I'm guessing it's the way I configured the multiple relationship between the two models.  Help me spot what I'm missing!

EDIT: As per badAPI's suggestion, `picture_ids` will contain only one value and not a list of values.  The following changes to my models produced a working one-to-many relationship:

```
class Post(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    cover_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pictures.id',
            use_alter=True, name='fk_post_cover_id'))
    cover = db.relationship('Picture', uselist=False, foreign_keys=cover_id,
            post_update=True)

class Picture(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pictures'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    position = db.Column(db.Integer)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))

    gallery = db.relationship('Post', foreign_keys=post_id,
            order_by='Picture.position',
            collection_class=ordering_list(position),
            backref=db.backref('gallery'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configured the relationship incorrectly. Your `picture_ids` column will not work for a one to many relationship, since you can only store a single picture_id in that column. So remove that column and use this to set up the gallery:

```
gallery = db.relationship('Picture', backref=db.backref('post', uselist=False))
```

Then you can remove the `post_id` column from the `Picture` class and just access all of the posts using `Picture.post`.

Comment: Still throws the same error.  Isn't `uselist` for setting up one-to-one relationships?  I need `gallery` to be a list of pictures related to post.

Comment: `uselist=False` is set on the backref, since each picture belongs to only one post. Did you try removing the other kwargs like `collection_class`, `order_by`, and `foreign_keys` to see which one is causing the problem?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this.  I removed `picture_ids` and used your version of `gallery` so no other kwargs as you suggested, still same error.  Unless you meant adding your version of `gallery` to Picture model?

Comment: Though your solution didn't work I've accepted your answer because you identified the problem.  Thanks!